# how to keep a minimum distance of 1 patch between itself and another agent when moving in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, distance, turtle-graphics

If the social_distancing variable is set to true the turtle must keep a minimum distance of 1 patch between itself and another agent when moving (i.e. check to see if another agent is in front before moving forward, a strategy to avoid collisions).

```
to social-distancing
  if social_distancing = true[
  ask turtles [
    if any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    [
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
  ]
    
end
```

I am new to netlogo and I have no idea if what I did here is the right way. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

That could work but you need "not" as in

```
 if not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
```

Also,  you might consider rotating the heading of stuck turtles or that logic will result in a log-jam of turtles in little clusters all unable to move.

I didn't verify my syntax but here's the idea:

```
 ifelse not any? other turtles-on patch-ahead 1
    [
      fd 1
    ]
    [
       set heading ( heading + random 90 ) 
    ]
```